# Understanding STM32 datasheet regarding decoupling capacitors

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, decoupling-capacitor, stm32f0

I'm trying to understand what ST recommends for decoupling caps for STM32F030CC.

The diagram in the datasheet shows "2x100 nF" caps on the Vdd/Vss pairs. Does this mean 2 parallel 100nF caps per Vdd/Vss pair? Or are they referring to the total number of 100nF caps needed, i.e. if there are 2 Vdd/Vss pairs then it's 1 100nF cap per Vdd/Vss pair, for a total of 2 100nF caps?

[STM32F030 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f030cc.pdf)

[image: power supply schematic from the STM32F030 datasheet]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are referring to the total number of capacitors needed.

ST has a useful document: "[AN4325 - Getting started with STM32F030xx and STM32F070xx series hardware development](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00089834.pdf)"

Inside, it is a bit more clear:

[image]

And they explain it directly in Section 5.4:

[image]